# Get the sum of two span value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Is it possible to get the sum of a text box and a span? I've tried calling the class name of the span but when I tried to alert it. It just says Undefined. Is it possible if I sum span 1 and span 2 it will change the data of span 2 ? ex is Span1 (Additional Price) + Span2(BasePrice)? Or should I just create a 3rd span where the base price will be stored? thank you in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/k5zh9m4d/3/

```
<section class="py-5">
<br><br>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Menu</h1>
<br><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample milk tea">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h3>Item 1</h3>
        <p>Item Desc</p>
        <hr>
        <h4>
        <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"
        disabled>
          <i 
          class="fa fa-glass fa-lg"
          aria-hidden="true">
          </i>70.00
        </button>
        </h4>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#MLKT-001">
        <i
        class="fa fa-cart-plus"
        aria-hidden="true">
        </i>
        Order
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
  <br><br>
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample milk tea">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h3>Item 2</h3>
        <p>Item Desc 2</p>
        <hr>
        <h4>
        <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"
        disabled>
          <i 
          class="fa fa-glass fa-lg"
          aria-hidden="true">
          </i>70.00
        </button>
        </h4>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#MLKT-002">
        <i
        class="fa fa-cart-plus"
        aria-hidden="true">
        </i>
        Order
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div
class="modal fade"
id="MLKT-001"
tabindex="-1"
role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
        </h5>
        <button
        type="button"
        class="close"
        data-dismiss="modal"
        aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
     </div>
 <form action="#" id="orderform">
   <div class="modal-body">
     <b>Size</b>&nbsp;<small>Pick 1</small>
       <div class="form-check">
        <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="radiobutton"
        id="rbtn1"
        value="0.00">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
         Regular - PHP 0.00
         </label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-check">
        <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="radiobutton"
        id="rbtn2"
        value="10.00">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
         Regular - PHP 10.00
         </label>
       </div>
          <p>Total: PHP <span id="total" class="total">0</span></p>
   </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-secondary"
        data-dismiss="modal">
        Cancel
        </button>
        <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-success">
        Order now - 
        <span>PHP 70.00</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div
class="modal fade"
id="MLKT-002"
tabindex="-1"
role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
        </h5>
        <button
        type="button"
        class="close"
        data-dismiss="modal"
        aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
     </div>
 <form action="#" id="orderform">
   <div class="modal-body">
     <b>Size</b>&nbsp;<small>Pick 1</small>
       <div class="form-check">
        <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="radiobutton"
        id="rbtn1"
        value="0.00">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
         Regular - PHP 0.00
         </label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-check">
        <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="radiobutton"
        id="rbtn2"
        value="10.00">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
         Large - PHP 10.00
         </label>
       </div>
          <p>Total: PHP <span id="total" class="total">0</span></p>
   </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-secondary"
        data-dismiss="modal">
        Cancel
        </button>
        <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-success">
        Order now - 
        <span class="baseprice">PHP 80.00</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
     </div>
  </section>

\\script
<script>
$(":radio").on("change", function(){
   $(this).closest('form').find('.total').text(Number(this.value));
   var addprice = document.querySelector('.total').value;
   var basepirce = document.querySelector('.basepirce').value;
   var totalprice = Number(addprice) + Number(basepirce)
    
    $(".basepirce").text(totalprice);
});
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `document.querySelector('.basepirce')`. Maybe you meant to write **baseprice**? Also be aware that **PHP 80.00** will not validate to a valid number using plain `Number()`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have mistakes in your html layout. `<label>` shouldn't go into the `<input>` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for more info.

Second of, using `.value` to extract text from span will not work, because it only works with inputs, selects or textarea [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Try using another method to get value out of span. And there is also no class named `'.basepirce'`.

Comment: The HTML is not incorrect as you can even see in the link you provided if you scrolled down.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the correct selector and value in the radio button instead of text .

Did some changes in your fiddle and it is working , you may check the following

https://jsfiddle.net/mfb08h2L/2/

```
> var addprice = $(this).val(); var basepirce = $(".basepirce").text()
> var totalprice = Number(addprice) + Number(basepirce)
> $(".basepirce").text(totalprice);
```